# understanding routes and templates html in angularjs, simples example possible

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm trying to embed angularjs into my existing asp.net mvc4 app.

(Views/Shared/)
**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
     <head>
       <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script src="/js/main.js"></script>     
     </head>
   <body>
        @RenderBody()
   </body>
</html>
```

**/js/main.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
module.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/topics", {
        controller: "topicsController",
        templateUrl: "/js/templates/topicsView.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
});

app.controller("topicsController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.testData = "some dummy data";
});
```

**/js/templates/topicsView.html**

```
<h1>topics template view, dummy object </h1>
{{ testData }}
```

and inside **/Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
<div data-ng-view=""></div>
```

I'm trying to navigate to /topics using **#/topics** url but nothing is rendered (blank page, not 404), not even h1 title from `templates/topicsView.html`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) module. Try this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include angular-routes.js along with angular.js and then include ngRoutes modules as a dependency when you create the angular main app  module.